# Perforce Visual Studio (2010) Plugin - Not opening perforce dialog?

Tags: perforce

Given: 
-Perforce visual studio (used with 2010) plugin installed
- Selected as SCC via Tools/Options/Plugin settings:

When I try to open SCC solution from File/Open from Source Control visual studio locks up (and does not pop up the pv4 connection dialog).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [P4VS](http://www.perforce.com/product/components/visual-studio-plug-in), it is better. P4SCC never worked fine for me neither.

Answer (score 0):

Is your *P4* server online? Can you connect to it using the *P4V* client? The *P4SCC* (the Visual Studio plugin) unfortunately locks-up when the server is offline.

Also... the better workflow is to use *P4V* to sync the project to your workspace and then open it via the normal File/Open menu.

Comment: The server is definitely online as I can interact with depot/workspaces via PV4.  I just started using perforce so this is the first that I have tried the VS plugin.